# How do I make a single image responsive in CSS flex or grid and have image-text columns?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, responsive

This should be easy...but for some reason, I can't get my brains around this. I want to have two columns next to each other. Left column for text and right column for an image. Also, I wanted to use flex, but whether I include the  in the HTML or try creating a background image, I just cannot get the img to be responsive.

First, I tried using a grid, because this could get more complex further down the road. However, the img wouldn't be responsive either. I think I am missing an essential concept (even though I set width: 100%, height: auto and max-width: 100%) with responsive images.

In the end, I need something that could look-and-feel like this (I will have text-image and image-text layouts):
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>EB-6590</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.processed.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sh-ref-nfh2-container">
        <div class="sh-ref-nfh2-content">
            <div class="sh-ref-nfh2-left">
                Left
            </div>
            <div class="sh-ref-nfh2-right">
                 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/683x600.png?text=Responsive">       
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the (S)CSS:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sh-ref-nfh2-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 600px;

   .sh-ref-nfh2-content {
       position: relative;
       width: 100%;
       height: inherit;
       max-width: 1366px;
       display: -webkit-box;
       display: -ms-flexbox;
       display: flex;
       -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
       -webkit-box-direction: normal;
       -ms-flex-direction: row;
       flex-direction: row;
       -webkit-box-align: center;
       -ms-flex-align: center;
       align-items: center;    
   
      .sh-ref-nfh2-left {
          -webkit-box-flex: 0;
          -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
          flex: 0 0 50%;
          border: #eee solid 1px;
      }
      .sh-ref-nfh2-right {
          -webkit-box-flex: 0;
          -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
          flex: 0 0 50%;
          border: #ccc solid 1px;

          img {
              width: 100%;
              height: auto;
              max-width: 100%;
          }
      }
  }  
}
```

https://codepen.io/binggeli/project/editor/ZpnRaB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Viewport Units** like `vw` for **width** and `vh` for **height** instead of `px` and `%` because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive.

It will surely work but if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to help you.

Comment: – Wow! I am astonished. I used vw for the `flex: 0 0 50vw` and now the image is responsive. I'm not sure why it wouldn't be responsive with other measurement units, but I'm glad you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @ShawnSpencer I am so happy to hear that my solution worked for you and thanks for accepting and upvoting my answer, it means a lot to me. I hope I get more chances to assist you.